# Android Import from Git not working

Tags: android, git, android-studio, import

I've created an Android project and pushed it into Git (with default generated `gitignore`).

Now if I try to pull it from another computer and import it to Android Studio, it says that it can't load 2 modules (.iml files). I have deleted those, as suggested.

But then a Gradle build error comes up:

> style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryLightGrey (aka package/name:attr/colorName)' not found.

I moved my colors into `values/colors.xml` and it was working fine when I pushed it.

Another thing I noticed is, that inside any `Activity.java` file, Android Studio cannot resolve the `R.java` class.

Maybe Git and Android Studio don't get along well, since the app ran just fine before pushing it and checking it out again.

Does anybody know a solution to my problem?

***Solution:*** I had a problem with my style file, it used some of the color defined in `colors.xml`. I deleted the references and it worked again!

Comment: I already had the problem where Android Studio cannot find R. To fix the problem, try Build > Clean Project / Rebuild Project and/or File > Invalidate Cache and restart Android Studio

Comment: by mistake you import wrong class in import , just cross check all imports , after that you can resolve R .

Comment: That doesn't work for me sadly, I still get the same error